# Rcpp code crashes R

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I have the following C++ code :

```
NumericVector testFromontcpp(NumericMatrix z1, NumericMatrix z2, int Nbootstrap){
  int dim1 = z1.nrow();
  int dim2 = z2.nrow();
  int dimension = z1.ncol();
  int N = dim1 + dim2;
  NumericVector TKeps(Nbootstrap+1);
  cout << "toto";
  double bb[N][N];
  cout << "toto";
  return(TKeps);
}
```

I run it with Rcpp package : `sourceCpp("...")`. It works well if `z1.size()` is under 500. But for higher sizes, it crashes and closes R before the second "toto" is printed.

I would like to know :

- Am I doing something wrong here ?
- Or is this issue of size in Rcpp known ?
- Is there a solution to make my code run with `z1.size()` >0 ?

Thank you !

Comment: Yes, as Matthew told you your code is incorrect.  And I now added a better solution than his `vector<vector<double> >`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is even worse than Matthew says as

```
 double bb[N][N];
```

is simply **wrong** as C / C++ have no native two-dimensional structure.  You *always* create a long vector and then use clever indexing into it, see e.g. the old Numerical Recipes in C code for emulating matrices.

Here, this is plain silly as we **do** have matrix types, so use one:

```
 Rcpp::NumericMatrix bb(N,N);
```

The bigger isue that with modern C++, as well as the classes provided by Rcpp, you should *never* have to use `malloc`/`free` or `new`/`delete`.

Comment: +1 for never using `malloc`/`free` or `new`/`delete` (except in resource handles themselves).

Comment: Is there any documentation on why `malloc`/`free` or `new`/`delete` are not needed in Rcpp? I ask because I have a memory leak in an Rcpp function that only uses Rcpp-classes and I'm trying to track it down and fix it.

Comment: Yes, the [Writing R Extensions](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-exts.html) manual that comes with every copy of R.  In particular it stresses that for objects managed by R and returnd you need to allocate from it pool.  For you own code you can do whatever you want ... and then fix your own bugs :)   My meta-point is that the STL constructs like `std::vector` give you the ability to code without having to managed memory as in the old C days.

Answer (score 8):

Despite what others have said, multi dimensional arrays are perfectly valid. However, specifying the dimensions at runtime is only supported in C99. Compilers choose to honour that, but it is not standard. Here is what I get with clang and the `-pedantic` option:

```
array.cpp:13:15: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
  double bb[N][N];
              ^
array.cpp:13:12: warning: variable length arrays are a C99 feature [-Wvla-extension]
  double bb[N][N];
       ^
```

See also this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/737240/c-c-array-size-at-run-time-w-o-dynamic-allocation-is-allowed) which is related.

Comment: In fact, this "feature" of C99 was deliberately not adopted by C++.  See section 1.2.3 of *The C++ Programming Language, 4th edition*.  Stroustrup calls it a "misfeature."

Comment: Sure. And I agree and look forward for dynarray, etc .. but it is the runtime dimensions that are not standard. multi dim arrays with compile time constant dimensions are perfectly fine, and as you said in your answer, what happened is likely to be stack problems

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is in this line:

```
double bb[N][N];
```

That is allocating a large number of elements on the stack, and you're running out of stack space.  Allocate on the heap instead.

If possible, I would use a `std::vector<std::vector<double>>` for this.  That is a resource handle that allocates its memory on the heap.  You don't indicate what you're doing with `bb`, so I can't tell whether it is possible.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16411448/1290634

Comment: Why?  If a matrix is needed, use one: `Rcpp::NumericMatrix bb(N,N);`